# Remove unwanted share option from cordova share ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, social-networking

How can hide or remove unwanted share option with cordova share function
I used following function to share message

```
$cordovaSocialSharing
                    .share(" Message ", "Subject", null,"test") // Share via native share sheet
                    .then(function(result) {
                      console.log("Message share");          
                    }, function(err) {
                  // An error occured. Show a message to the user
                  });
```

I want to hide or remove unwanted share option ..
I need only few options like facebook, twitter , google+, tumblr etc...
Please help me to solve this issue